# Scaling a rotated rectangle and find the new control points and centre

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, css-transforms

This code in the code pen link I am going to share is a bit complicated and dense, so I am actually asking not for code but for advice.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLEedg?editors=0010

It is about scaling a rotated rectangle and find the new scaled rectangle's vertex coordinates.

When I rotate the rectangle I translate its center to 0,0 of viewport and do the rotation. Then I translate back to its old place. It works.

Then i do a scale moving the `transform-origin` to the bottom right of the rectangle. To avoid the jump I compensate the scale amount and also the translation which the rotation action applied to my control points. In the end when I move the `transform origin` to the rotated bottom left of the rectangle I see no jump. I calculate a new bounding box with the new control points (not rotated coordinates but scaled versions.)

After that I do a scale with the new `transform-origin` with the same method. This time I take the new scaled but not rotated new bounding box and do a rotation with same method to find the new scaled and rotated control point coordinates.

I expect them to be exactly at the images vertices but they are a bit off.

Probably it's about scaling from a rotated control point's origin and not compensating properly.

To reproduce the problem in the code pen link I share.

First rotate an arbitrary amount to left.

Then scale by draging the top left handle to the left.

The little black dots should land exactly on the center of green handles.

The little black dots are the new control point coordinates I calculate,
The red stroked rectangle is the new bounding box which gets rotated at 0,0 and translate back to calculate the new control points. The blue target with red fill is the `transform-origin` of the image. The yellow target with green fill is the `transform-origin` of the handles which I don't update intentionally not to get confused. The blue fill circle with larger radius with opacity is the new calculated center from the little black dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem like below, i would love to hear a better solution.

This covers finding the new vertices and center after rotation and scale operations.

All the below code block should be evaluated after every scale event and rotation event.

Which probably will be the drag event for the handle.

`heightOfRectangle` and `WidthOfRectangle` should be the scaled values.

Ex. if you have current scale of 1.3 then `heightOfRectangle` should be your `initial rectangle's height*1.3`

`rotationAngle` should be the sum of the all rotation angles applied before in radians.

`alpha` is the  `Math.atan2(heightOfRectangle,WidthOfRectangle)`;

`r` is `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(WidthOfRectangle,2)+Math.pow(heightOfRectangle,2))/2`
in other words hypotenus shared by two right triangles which makes the rectangle;

Assuming that you overcame the transform origin issues and can scale the
rectangle from different handles preventing the transform origin jumps, active handle is the handle you drag
and the opposite side is where the transform origin is located.
For example if you drag from the top left handle the origin should be located 
at the bottom right handle location.

`activeHandle` is the handle you drag.

`tl` for topleft, `o` for origin `br` for bottomright and so on..

`tc` means top center for my code where i drag for the rotation.

It simply means the rotation from origin event.

the values that start with `old` should be your last handle locations before this rotation.
the values that start with `new` will be your new handle locations after this rotation.

`rx` is an abbreviation for rotated x
`ry` is an abbreviation for rotated y

You can still view the pen here, with solved problem.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLEedg?editors=0010

You can view `updateControlPoints` function on line 251.

```
 var cosRot = Math.cos(rotationAngle);
 var sinRot = Math.sin(rotationAngle);

 if (activeHandle === 'tc') {

     var cosAMinusRot = Math.cos(alpha - rotationAngle);
     var sinAMinusRot = Math.sin(alpha - rotationAngle);
     var cosAPlusRot = Math.cos(alpha + rotationAngle);
     var sinAPlusRot = Math.sin(alpha + rotationAngle);
     var cos90APlusRot = Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 - alpha + rotationAngle);
     var sin90APlusRot = Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 - alpha + rotationAngle);
     var ox = old_ox; //means current ox
     var oy = old_oy; //means current oy
     //tl
     var new_x = -r * cosAPlusRot + ox
     var new_y = -r * sinAPlusRot + oy
     new_tl.rx = new_x;
     new_tl.ry = new_y;
     //tr           

     new_x = +r * sin90APlusRot + ox
     new_y = -r * cos90APlusRot + oy
     new_tr.rx = new_x;
     new_tr.ry = new_y;
     //bl
     new_x = -r * cosAMinusRot + ox
     new_y = +r * sinAMinusRot + oy
     new_bl.rx = new_x;
     new_bl.ry = new_y;
     //br
     new_x = +r * cosAPlusRot + ox
     new_y = +r * sinAPlusRot + oy
     new_br.rx = new_x;
     new_br.ry = new_y;

 }

 else if (activeHandle === 'tl') {

     var cosAPlusRot = Math.cos(alpha + rotationAngle);
     var sinAPlusRot = Math.sin(alpha + rotationAngle);

     new_tl.rx = old_br.rx - 2 * r * cosAPlusRot;
     new_tl.ry = old_br.ry - 2 * r * sinAPlusRot;

     new_bl.rx = old_br.rx - WidthOfRectangle * cosRot;
     new_bl.ry = old_br.ry - WidthOfRectangle * sinRot;

     new_tr.rx = old_br.rx + HeightOfRectangle * sinRot;
     new_tr.ry = old_br.ry - HeightOfRectangle * cosRot;

     new_ox = old_br.rx - r * cosAPlusRot;
     new_oy = old_br.ry - r * sinAPlusRot;


 } else if (activeHandle === 'tr') {

     var cos180APlusRot = Math.cos(Math.PI - alpha + rotationAngle);
     var sin180APlusRot = Math.sin(Math.PI - alpha + rotationAngle);

     new_tl.rx = old_bl.rx + HeightOfRectangle * sinRot;
     new_tl.ry = old_bl.ry - HeightOfRectangle * cosRot;

     new_br.rx = old_bl.rx + WidthOfRectangle * cosRot;
     new_br.ry = old_bl.ry + WidthOfRectangle * sinRot;

     new_tr.rx = old_bl.rx - 2 * r * cos180APlusRot;
     new_tr.ry = old_bl.ry - 2 * r * sin180APlusRot;

     new_ox = old_bl.rx - r * cos180APlusRot;
     new_oy = old_bl.ry - r * sin180APlusRot;




 } else if (activeHandle === 'bl') {

     var cosAPlus90MinusRot = Math.cos(alpha + Math.PI / 2 - rotationAngle);
     var sinAPlus90MinusRot = Math.sin(alpha + Math.PI / 2 - rotationAngle);

     new_bl.rx = old_tr.rx - 2 * r * sinAPlus90MinusRot;
     new_bl.ry = old_tr.ry - 2 * r * cosAPlus90MinusRot;

     new_br.rx = old_tr.rx - HeightOfRectangle * sinRot;
     new_br.ry = old_tr.ry + HeightOfRectangle * cosRot;

     new_tl.rx = old_tr.rx - WidthOfRectangle * cosRot;
     new_tl.ry = old_tr.ry - WidthOfRectangle * sinRot;

     new_ox = old_tr.rx - r * sinAPlus90MinusRot;
     new_oy = old_tr.ry - r * cosAPlus90MinusRot;



 } else if (activeHandle === 'br') {

     var cosAPlusRot = Math.cos(alpha + rotationAngle);
     var sinAPlusRot = Math.sin(alpha + rotationAngle);

     new_bl.rx = old_tl.rx - HeightOfRectangle * sinRot;
     new_bl.ry = old_tl.ry + HeightOfRectangle * cosRot;

     new_br.rx = old_tl.rx + 2 * r * cosAPlusRot;
     new_br.ry = old_tl.ry + 2 * r * sinAPlusRot;

     new_tr.rx = old_tl.rx + WidthOfRectangle * cosRot;
     new_tr.ry = old_tl.ry + WidthOfRectangle * sinRot;

     new_ox = old_tl.rx + r * cosAPlusRot;
     new_oy = old_tl.ry + r * sinAPlusRot;



 }
```